# 'VERIFY_CLONEDB' is not a recognized option

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are using version of SQL Server following and version update not allowed at my work:

Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4583456) - 14.0.2037.2 (X64)

I'm trying to clone a database but I get `"'VERIFY_CLONEDB' is not a recognized option"` error.

`DBCC CLONEDATABASE (AdventureWorks, AdventureWorks_Clone) WITH VERIFY_CLONEDB;     GO`

**What can i use instead of this method:**

Comment: I strongly urge you to update to the latest CU, it has security and performance fixes, as well as new features as you have seen. And it's free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VERIFY_CLONEDB` isn't supported in the version you are using. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-clonedatabase-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments):

> VERIFY_CLONEDB
> Verifies the consistency of the new database. This option is required if the cloned database is intended for production use. Enabling VERIFY_CLONEDB also disables statistics and query store collection, thus it is equivalent to running WITH VERIFY_CLONEDB, NO_STATISTICS, NO_QUERYSTORE. This option is available starting with SQL Server 2014 (12.x) SP3, SQL Server 2016 (13.x) SP2, and **SQL Server 2017 (14.x) CU8**.

You need to install at least CU8 to take advantage of this feature (we're on CU25 at the moment).